# Block quote with big quotation marks

Tags: color, punctuation, quoting

How can I create a block quote enviroment with big quotation marks similar to the [Cquote Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aCquote) of Wikipedia?

Additionally it would be nice to place  both quotation marks and quote in a colored box and to have the author closer to the citation.

Comment: JFYI: See now also [Block quote with big quotation marks and opening quote on bottom](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98984/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks-and-opening-quote-on-bottom).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here's one solution using `TikZ` which defines a new environment using the `framed` package. You should  preferably compile this with `xelatex` or `lualatex`, since it gives the easiest access to a wide range of fonts.  I've added code to make it run under `pdflatex` as well.

The code has now been updated to allow some flexibility in the formatting of the different components of the quotation, and the environment takes two arguments:

### Environment Syntax

> ```
>  \begin{shadequote}[<alignment>]{<author>}
>     text of quote
>  \end{shadequote}
> ```

### Code

```
% !TEX TS-program = xeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{framed}

% conditional for xetex or luatex
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi
%
\ifxetexorluatex%
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{libertine} % or use \setmainfont to choose any font on your system
  \newfontfamily\quotefont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O} % selects Libertine as the quote font
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package
  \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-LF}} % selects Libertine as the quote font
\fi

\newcommand*\quotesize{60} % if quote size changes, need a way to make shifts relative
% Make commands for the quotes
\newcommand*{\openquote}
   {\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=-4ex,yshift=-2.5ex]
   \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{\quotesize}{\quotesize}\selectfont``};\kern0pt}

\newcommand*{\closequote}[1]
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=4ex,yshift={#1}]
   \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{\quotesize}{\quotesize}\selectfont''};}

% select a colour for the shading
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Azure}

\newcommand*\shadedauthorformat{\emph} % define format for the author argument

% Now a command to allow left, right and centre alignment of the author
\newcommand*\authoralign[1]{%
  \if#1l
    \def\authorfill{}\def\quotefill{\hfill}
  \else
    \if#1r
      \def\authorfill{\hfill}\def\quotefill{}
    \else
      \if#1c
        \gdef\authorfill{\hfill}\def\quotefill{\hfill}
      \else\typeout{Invalid option}
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
% wrap everything in its own environment which takes one argument (author) and one optional argument
% specifying the alignment [l, r or c]
%
\newenvironment{shadequote}[2][l]%
{\authoralign{#1}
\ifblank{#2}
   {\def\shadequoteauthor{}\def\yshift{-2ex}\def\quotefill{\hfill}}
   {\def\shadequoteauthor{\par\authorfill\shadedauthorformat{#2}}\def\yshift{2ex}}
\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
{\shadequoteauthor\quotefill\closequote{\yshift}\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}

\begin{document}

\begin{shadequote}[l]{Douglas Adams}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.
\end{shadequote}

\begin{shadequote}[r]{Douglas Adams}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.
\end{shadequote}

\begin{shadequote}[c]{Douglas Adams}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.
\end{shadequote}

\begin{shadequote}{}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.
\end{shadequote}

\end{document}
```

In this code, the font for the quotation marks is set independently of the main document font. This is because depending on the main font you choose, the very large quotation marks will not look good; Linux Libertine has pretty quotes that seem appropriate for the purpose. If you want to use this environment with another main document font,  remove/change the `\usepackage{libertine}`.

### Sample output

[image: output of code]

Comment: @Alun: Why do you define `\quotefont`? libertine is already present.

Comment: @Herbert Because these are decorative elements, it makes sense to define the font for the quotes independent of the document font.  For example, if you just use Computer Modern, the big quotes look quite silly; The libertine font has a pretty quote for this purpose, and I would use it with most document fonts.

Comment: @Alun: You know, that I know that ... ;-) But then it makes sense to use another text font in your example, if you want to show this behaviour.

Comment: @Herbert I tried to make that clear in the code comments. I figured that anyone who wanted to play around with other fonts would figure it out. I'll add a comment to the text of the answer.

Comment: This is very nice! However, id one doesn't separate the author via \par from the quote the spacing of the closing quotation mark is somewhat of. Maybe there is a simple fix for that? It works nicer in Herbert's version.

Comment: I made things this way deliberately, since the author of the quote shouldn't be in the scope of the quotation marks (IMO). However, if you want it that way, you can add a `\par` before the `\hfill` command in the end code of the `shadequote` environment. One difference also between my version and Herbert's is that in his, the quotation mark is inside the quote environment and as a result the quote wraps under the quotatation marks instead of inside them. Again, these are esthetic decisions.

Comment: Is there an easy way of getting the author on the right?

Comment: @ChristianJonassen It's not too hard to do, but I'll need to update the code in my answer to do it without a pure hack. I can do that later tonight.

Comment: That would be much appreciated. I tried a variety of things, but they either increased the whitespace between the quote and the author (by \begin{flushright}), or didn't put the author's name on the right, but rather somewhere in the middle (by \hfill) ... it would be great to have/see a working solution since I'm clearly missing something ... :-)

Comment: @ChristianJonassen Please see the heavily revised code. I think I need to turn this into a package. :)

Comment: You're awesome. Feel free to turn this into a package, you have my full support! :D

Comment: @AlanMunn: I'd like to set this beautiful quote environment flush right, and leave the lower quotation mark hanging into the margin. I tried hacking a bit with \hspace{}, and the result is beautiful—but it is not a flexible approach. Do you have any idea how to realize this?

Comment: @ingo You just want the lower mark in the margin?  Wouldn't that look a little odd?  And you want the coloured box to be in the margin too, or just the quotation mark?

Comment: @AlanMunn, right, with the colored box it would loo weird. I use the quotation box in the following manner: it spans only ~50% of the text width, and is set flush right. The background has been removed. Now if the lower mark is in the margin it actually looks pretty sweet, because the text in the box is aligned with the right hand side margin.
See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanging_punctuation

NB: It might also look good to have both marks in the margin, if they were a bit smaller and the text still spanned the full width (as in your examples).

Comment: You are an artistic, thanks. (1) For very short quotes, people usually wish to make it centered? How may I do that? I am currently using an ugly, ad-hoc solution (by adding in `\qquad` by trail and error). (2) How may I selectively disable `\emph` in the author field? Imagine: _Richard Smith_, American Artist. Note the title is in its normal font.

Comment: I'm using it in a tufte-book document and the font size of the quoted text is smaller than the font size of the document. How can I fix that in the code above?

Comment: With beamer, the text isn't centered between the quotes. Any idea how to fix this? Otherwise, it runs great right out of the box.

Comment: @Chernoff I'm not sure why this happens, but you can adjust the value of `xshift` in the `\closequote` macro to `1ex` (or similar values) to adjust the positioning of the quote.

Comment: One more question: How do I increase the space between the quote and the author name? Beamer puts them right up against each other.

Comment: @Chernoff Again, not sure the reason, but you can add  `\vspace{1ex}` (or similar value) before the `\emph` in the `\shadedauthorformat` definition.

Comment: Shouldn't have bothered to write `cfr-dquote` if I'd known all this existed :-).

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to make the coloured box have rounded corners? I've tried various arguments passed in to the `\tikz` command with no luck.

Comment: @ncrypticus In this solution, the box itself is not made by TikZ, it's made by the `framed` package which doesn't have any rounded corner option. Only the placement of the quotation marks themselves is made with TikZ. So if you want rounded corners on the boxes I would recommend using one of the other answers that use TikZ to create the box as well.

Answer (score 34):

(We just got another question asking for something similar: [Quote style like on owni.eu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28414/86).  I wasn't aware of this question when I started to answer that one, but on becoming aware of it decided to post my answer here instead.)

It's also TikZ-based but slightly different to Alan's as the whole thing ends up in a TikZ node.  This does mean that it won't work with page-breaking.  One could also adapt the quote marks from Alan's version to make them look a bit better.

Here's the result:

[image: fancy quotes]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter

\tikzset{%
  fancy quotes/.style={
    text width=\fq@width pt,
    align=justify,
    inner sep=1em,
    anchor=north west,
    minimum width=\linewidth,
  },
  fancy quotes width/.initial={.8\linewidth},
  fancy quotes marks/.style={
    scale=8,
    text=white,
    inner sep=0pt,
  },
  fancy quotes opening/.style={
    fancy quotes marks,
  },
  fancy quotes closing/.style={
    fancy quotes marks,
  },
  fancy quotes background/.style={
    show background rectangle,
    inner frame xsep=0pt,
    background rectangle/.style={
      fill=gray!25,
      rounded corners,
    },
  }
}

\newenvironment{fancyquotes}[1][]{%
\noindent
\tikzpicture[fancy quotes background]
\node[fancy quotes opening,anchor=north west] (fq@ul) at (0,0) {``};
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(fq@ul.east)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fq@width}{\linewidth - 2*\pgf@x}
\node[fancy quotes,#1] (fq@txt) at (fq@ul.north west) \bgroup}
{\egroup;
\node[overlay,fancy quotes closing,anchor=east] at (fq@txt.south east) {''};
\endtikzpicture}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{fancyquotes}
\lipsum[1]
\end{fancyquotes}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is just to provide some dummy text.

Comment: I like this one a lot and have started to use it in my documents.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks seriously good in documents. Thanks!

Comment: Just had a request on [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/11644/zitate-mit-tikz) to have the box in twocolumn mode taking up just one column. Basically, `s/textwidth/columnwidth/g`. Can you add a line explaining and maybe another screenshot?

Comment: @Johannes_B Feel free to edit the answer with that change.  As this is over three years old, I don't feel able to resurrect it myself.

Comment: @Johannes_B @LoopSpace This is great! This creates no spacing between paragraphs within the block quote, however. How can I modify it so that there is normal spacing between paragraphs within the fancyquotes environment? I tried adding `\setlength{\baselineskip}{16pt}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` but neither one worked.

Answer (score 28):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Azure}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@right
\def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
\def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
\def\endshadequote{%
  \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
\@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
\@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{shadequote}
Some quoted words
\end{shadequote}

\begin{shadequote*}
Some quoted words
\end{shadequote*}

\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using your code in a minimal example works great, but when I copy it to a large document I work on I get the error "You can't use '\spacefactor' in vertical mode". Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: you'd forgotten the `makeatletter` ... `makeatother`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took me quite a while to figure out what happend, but you were right, I messed up the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands. This happend after exporting some code from LyX, at this step LyX put some additional `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around my custom code.

Comment: If there is a line break before the closing quote, it looks a bit strange. I don't have a real good suggestion, but I think placing simple a `nolinebreak` makes things a bit better. This means one would have to replace the line   `\if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}` by  `\nolinebreak\if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}`. This is a comment and not an edit, because I'm unsure if it's the best solution.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in my thesis which is based on `classicthesis` but the problem is, it mess with all my fonts and change them. What am I doing wrong here? The same holds for @Herbert 's answer.

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is old, but I may as well share my simple attempt.

Note: requires `\usepackage{xcolor}`

The command itself:

```tex
\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]{\begin{center}\fcolorbox{white}{blue!15!gray!15}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\vspace{10pt}\center\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}{\space\Huge``}{#1}{\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}\end{minipage}\smallbreak\end{minipage}}\end{center}}
```

Minimum working example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]{\begin{center}\fcolorbox{white}{blue!15!gray!15}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\vspace{10pt}\center\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}{\space\Huge``}{#1}{\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}\end{minipage}\smallbreak\end{minipage}}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\quotebox{Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.}
\end{document}
```

Example:

[image: Image of MWE]

Answer (score 7):

Had I known about this question, I would not have written `cfr-dquote`. However, I didn't, so I did. Here's a lightly modified version of my package for public consumption or rejection.

The package defines a command, `\dquote[<dimension>]{<long text>}{<short text}` which is intended to be used so that `<dimension>` is the width desired, `<long text>` is the quotation and `<short text>` is the attribution.

The package is based on Ti*k*Z and the appearance can be customised using the usual key-value interface. For example, I've never used this with a coloured background to the quotation, but that is easy to achieve by simply altering `quote style`.

For example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,babel,csquotes}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{cfr-dquote}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  dquote text font=\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont\Large\upshape,
  dquote attrib font=\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont\Huge\itshape,
  dquote={
    quote style/.style={align=justify, fill=blue!50!cyan, fill opacity=.2, text opacity=1, text=blue!15!darkgray},
    marks={
      size=\Huge,
      scale=4,
      color=blue!50!darkgray,
      opacity=.5,
    },
  },
}%
\dquote{%
  ‘Come, we shall have some fun now!’ thought Alice. ‘I'm glad they've begun asking riddles --- I believe I can guess that,’ she added aloud.

  ‘Do you mean that you think you can find out the answer to it?’ said the March Hare.

  ‘Exactly so,’ said Alice.

  ‘Then you should say what you mean,’ the March Hare went on.

  ‘I do,’ Alice hastily replied; ‘at least --- at least I mean what I say --- that's the same thing, you know.’

  ‘Not the same thing a bit!’ said the Hatter. ‘Why, you might just as well say that ‘I see what I eat’ is the same thing as ‘I eat what I see’!’

  ‘You might just as well say,’ added the March Hare, ‘that ‘I like what I get’ is the same thing as ‘I get what I like’!’

  ‘You might just as well say,’ added the Dormouse, which seemed to be talking in its sleep, ‘that ‘I breathe when I sleep’ is the same thing as ‘I sleep when I breathe’!’
}{Lewis Carroll}

\end{document}
```

produces the following output

[image: Alice quote]

The package consists of two files, `cfr-dquote.sty` and `cfr-dquote.tex`. In theory, the latter can be compiled alone, since it uses the `standalone` class, but don't be tempted to use it this way - that's just to make tweaks and debugging easier.

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{cfr-dquote.sty}
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% cfr-dquote.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}% LaTeX 2.09 can't be used (nor non-LaTeX)
[1994/12/01]% LaTeX date must December 1994 or later
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesPackageSVN{$Id: cfr-dquote.sty 7799 2018-07-20 01:52:15Z cfr $}
\RequirePackage{xcolor,pifont,standalone,xparse,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
\IfFileExists{tikzlibrarypicfix.code.tex}{\usetikzlibrary{picfix}}{}
\IfFileExists{tikzlibrarycfrexternal.code.tex}{\usetikzlibrary{cfrexternal}}{\usetikzlibrary{external}}
\NewDocumentCommand\dquotetextfonthook{}{\normalfont\large}
\NewDocumentCommand\dquoteattribfonthook{}{\normalfont\normalsize}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newlength\cfrdquoteparskip\setlength\cfrdquoteparskip{\parskip}%
  \newlength\cfrdquoteparindent\setlength\cfrdquoteparindent{\parindent}}
% BEGIN defaults
\tikzset{%
  dquote text font/.code={%
    \RenewDocumentCommand\dquotetextfonthook{}{#1}
  },
  dquote attrib font/.code={%
    \RenewDocumentCommand\dquoteattribfonthook{}{#1}
  },
  dquote/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /cfr-dquote/.cd,
      #1
    }
  },
  /cfr-dquote/quote style/.style={align=justify, color=blue!50!black},
  /cfr-dquote/quote/.style={/cfr-dquote/quote style, font=\dquotetextfonthook},
  /cfr-dquote/attrib/.style={/cfr-dquote/quote style, font=\dquoteattribfonthook},
  /cfr-dquote/quote mark/.style={color=\cfrdquotecolor, opacity=\cfrdquoteopacity, font=\cfrdquotesize, scale=\cfrdquotescale},
  /cfr-dquote/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cfrdquotewidth,
  text/.store in=\cfrdquotetext,
  attribution/.store in=\cfrdquoteattrib,
  width=120mm,
  text={Does dim o gwbl yn y fan hon!},
  attribution={Neb},
  marks/.code={%
    \tikzset{%
      /cfr-dquote/quote marks/.cd,
      #1
    }
  },
  quote marks/size/.store in=\cfrdquotesize,
  quote marks/scale/.store in=\cfrdquotescale,
  quote marks/color/.store in=\cfrdquotecolor,
  quote marks/opacity/.store in=\cfrdquoteopacity,
  marks={
    size=\Huge,
    scale=4,
    color=blue!50!cyan,
    opacity=.25,
  },
}
% END defaults
% BEGIN defn \dquote
\NewDocumentCommand\dquote { O {120mm} +m m }{%
  \tikzset{%
    external/export next=false,
    /cfr-dquote/.cd,
    width={#1},
    text={\setlength\parskip{\cfrdquoteparskip}\setlength\parindent{\cfrdquoteparindent}#2},
    attribution={#3}
  }%
  \input{cfr-dquote}%
}
% END defn \dquote
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{cfr-dquote.tex}
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
%BEGIN preamble
\csname standaloneignore\endcsname
\pdfminorversion=7
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesFileSVN{$Id: cfr-dquote.tex 7800 2018-07-20 01:58:28Z cfr $}
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pifont,biblatex}
% END preamble

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0pt]
    \node (quotation) [/cfr-dquote/quote, text width=\cfrdquotewidth]  {\cfrdquotetext};
    \node (attrib) [/cfr-dquote/attrib, below=of quotation, text width=\cfrdquotewidth] {\cfrdquoteattrib};
    \node (qlhs) [left=of quotation.north west, /cfr-dquote/quote mark, xshift=.25em, yshift=.25em, anchor=north east] {\ding{123}};
    \node (qrhs) [right=of quotation.south east, /cfr-dquote/quote mark, xshift=-.25em, yshift=-.75em, anchor=south west] {\ding{124}};
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \useasboundingbox (attrib.south -| qlhs.west) rectangle (quotation.north -| qrhs.east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,babel,csquotes}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{cfr-dquote}
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
\MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  dquote text font=\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont\Large\upshape,
  dquote attrib font=\fontfamily{LobsterTwo-LF}\selectfont\Huge\itshape,
  dquote={
    quote style/.style={align=justify, fill=blue!50!cyan, fill opacity=.2, text opacity=1, text=blue!15!darkgray},
    marks={
      size=\Huge,
      scale=4,
      color=blue!50!darkgray,
      opacity=.5,
    },
  },
}%
\dquote{%
  ‘Come, we shall have some fun now!’ thought Alice. ‘I'm glad they've begun asking riddles --- I believe I can guess that,’ she added aloud.

  ‘Do you mean that you think you can find out the answer to it?’ said the March Hare.

  ‘Exactly so,’ said Alice.

  ‘Then you should say what you mean,’ the March Hare went on.

  ‘I do,’ Alice hastily replied; ‘at least --- at least I mean what I say --- that's the same thing, you know.’

  ‘Not the same thing a bit!’ said the Hatter. ‘Why, you might just as well say that ‘I see what I eat’ is the same thing as ‘I eat what I see’!’

  ‘You might just as well say,’ added the March Hare, ‘that ‘I like what I get’ is the same thing as ‘I get what I like’!’

  ‘You might just as well say,’ added the Dormouse, which seemed to be talking in its sleep, ‘that ‘I breathe when I sleep’ is the same thing as ‘I sleep when I breathe’!’
}{Lewis Carroll}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had some issues getting the other solutions here to work with a particularly troublesome set of packages, so I rewrote a solution around the `adjustbox` package.

```
\newlength\shadeDepth
\newcommand{\shadequote}[2]{%
    \begin{center}\begin{adjustbox}{bgcolor=WhiteSmoke,margin=0.5mm,rndcorners=2.5pt}
        \adjustbox{center,minipage=0.9\linewidth,gstore totalheight=\shadeDepth}{#1}%
        \adjustbox{rlap,valign=b,raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.75em,scale={-1}{-1}}{\Huge``}%
        \hspace{-\linewidth}%
        \adjustbox{rlap,valign=B,raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.50em,left=\linewidth}{\Huge``}%
        \hspace{-\linewidth}%
        \ifblank{#2}{}{\adjustbox{left,raise=-\shadeDepth/2-2em,minipage=\linewidth}{#2}}%
    \end{adjustbox}\end{center}
}
```

which can be spaced out a bit for readability as

```
\newlength\shadeDepth
\newcommand{\Newerquotebox}[2]{%
    \begin{center}%
            \adjustbox{bgcolor=WhiteSmoke,rndcorners=2.5pt}{%
                    \adjustbox{%fbox,
                            center,%
                            minipage=0.9\linewidth,%
                            gstore totalheight=\shadeDepth}{#1}%
                    \adjustbox{%fbox,
                            rlap,valign=b,%
                            raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.75em,%
                            scale={-1}{-1}}{\Huge``}%
                    \hspace{-\linewidth}
                    \adjustbox{%fbox,
                            rlap,valign=B,%
                            raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.50em,%
                            scale={+1}{+1},%
                            left=\linewidth}{\Huge``}%
                    \hspace{-\linewidth}
                    \ifblank{#2}%
                            {}%
                            {\adjustbox{left,raise=-\shadeDepth/2-2em,minipage=\linewidth}{#2}}%

                }
    \end{center}
}
```

usage takes the form of `\shadequote{quote}{citation}`

---

#### Minimal Working Version

The above can be used as

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[multi=pane,border=4mm,tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox,libertine,soul,standalone,xcolor}

\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-LF}}

    \newlength\shadeDepth
    \newcommand{\shadequote}[2]{%
        \begin{center}\begin{adjustbox}{bgcolor=WhiteSmoke,margin=0.5mm,rndcorners=2.5pt}
            \adjustbox{center,minipage=0.9\linewidth,gstore totalheight=\shadeDepth}{#1}%
            \adjustbox{rlap,valign=b,raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.75em,scale={-1}{-1}}{\Huge``}%
            \hspace{-\linewidth}%
            \adjustbox{rlap,valign=B,raise=\shadeDepth/2-1.50em,left=\linewidth}{\Huge``}%
            \hspace{-\linewidth}%   
            \ifblank{#2}{}{\adjustbox{left,raise=-\shadeDepth/2-2em,minipage=\linewidth}{#2}}%
        \end{adjustbox}\end{center}
    }

\colorlet{soulhlb}{DeepSkyBlue!30}
\colorlet{soulhly}{yellow!50}
\colorlet{soulhll}{lime!30}
\colorlet{soulhlp}{pink!30}
\colorlet{soulhlpr}{MediumOrchid!30}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlb}[1]{{\sethlcolor{soulhlb}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hly}[1]{{\sethlcolor{soulhly}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hll}[1]{{\sethlcolor{soulhll}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlp}[1]{{\sethlcolor{soulhlp}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlpr}[1]{{\sethlcolor{soulhlpr}\hl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pane}%_
        \shadequote{%
            Pulmonary surfactant is a complex and highly surface active material composed of lipids and proteins which is found in the fluid lining the alveolar surface of the lungs. Surfactant \hly{prevents alveolar collapse at low lung volume}, and \hlb{preserves bronchiolar patency during normal and forced respiration} (biophysical functions). In addition, it is \hlpr{involved in the protection of the lungs from injuries and infections caused by inhaled particles and micro-organisms} (immunological, non-biophysical functions).%
        }{in ``Pulmonary Surfactant in Health and Human Lung Diseases: State of the Art'' by Griese (1999).$^{1}$}
     \end{pane}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output of the form of

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice solution.