# Block quoting with big quotes on all the width of the page

Tags: margins, indentation, quoting

the following code ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks/16986#16986)) is very pretty but I would like the text quoted to occupy all the width of the page.

How can I achieve this ?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{libertine}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{framed}

    \newcommand*\openquote{%
        \makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}} 
    }
    \newcommand*\closequote{ %
        \makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}
    }
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}

    \makeatletter
        \newif\if@right
        \def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
        \def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
        \def\endshadequote{%
            \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
            \@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
        \@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
    \makeatother


\begin{document}

    \begin{shadequote}
        Some quoted words
    \end{shadequote}

    \begin{shadequote*}
        Some quoted words
    \end{shadequote*}

    \begin{shadequote}
        A common mistake that people make when trying to design something
        completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.

        \par \emph{Douglas Adams}
    \end{shadequote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, it is very easy to fix : I delete the quote environment.

Answer (score 6):

Add to those definitions

```
\newenvironment{xquote}
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=0pt\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item\relax}
  {\endlist}
```

and change `\begin{quote}` into `\begin{xquote}` and similarly `\end{quote}` into `\begin{xquote}`.

Comment: @projectmbc: rather than comment, it's better for future readers to vote up an answer, marking it as accepted when you're sure it does what you were looking for.

Comment: projetmbc hasn't enough reputation yet to upvote.