# Quote style like on owni.eu

Tags: tikz-pgf, quoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block quote with big quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks)

How can I reproduce with TikZ the quoting style from Owni.eu
http://owni.fr/2011/09/13/increvable-droit-dauteur/ in a environment?

I don't know how to move the quotation marks (see the cut part).

Comment: I might make sense for a solution to this question to connect with the `csquotes` package.

Comment: What you are asking for is very similar to what the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks delivers except that they marks are not cut.

Comment: @N.N. : I've already seen this thread, I like the one on Owni because it can be used with long quotations. I like the negative marks.

Comment: What I meant is that you can use the code in those answers as a start to produce what you're after. You could e.g. include here a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of how far you've gotten and we can help you complete it.

Comment: I've had a go at this, but I hadn't seen the thread that N.N. linked to when I did.  My solution is a bit different to Alan's, so I'm going to post it, but I'll post it at *that* question because I think that the two are close enough that we should have all the answers in one place.  So take a look at my solution there, if it isn't satisfactory then edit this question to explain why not (or, if you get enough reputation points, comment on that answer).  If it is okay, we'll close this question as a duplicate of that one to ensure that others can find the answer quickly.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9UerAzRQ : I've maked a .sty file, I don't know how to move the marks on the border.

Comment: @Pea: Andrew's solution at [block quote with big quotation marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks) seems to work great. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @Pea: We've closed this as a duplicate of that other one for now.  If none of the code there works for you, please edit this question to explain why it doesn't and what extra you'd like to achieve.  Once you've done that, flag this question for moderator attention and it will probably be reopened.