# How to create a 'fact box' or pull quote that is tied to the margins of your page?

Tags: positioning, boxes, quoting

I'd like to accomplish the following:

```
Ut convallis libero in   -------------------
urna ultrices accumsan. |                   |
Donec sed odio eros.    |  "an important    |
Donec viverra mi quis   |   quote that de-  |
quam pulvinar at        |   serves to be    |
malesuada arcu rhoncus. |   highlighted"    |
Cum sociis natoque      |   ---sourcename   |
                        |                   |
penatibus et magnis     |                   |
dis parturient montes,   -------------------
nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan 
ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis 
semper ac in est.
```

So a quote-box, pull-quote or fact box (whatever you'd call it) that highlights a quote within a colored box, sticks to the right- or left-margin of the page and makes the text flow around it. I've searched around and found some topics that were a bit similar ( [Block quote with big quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks) and [How do you create pull quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45709/how-do-you-create-pull-quotes) for instance), but not exactly. As you find this kind of style often within books, I was wondering if an existing package exist that does this for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is easily accomplished using the [`wrapfig` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) if you're willing to specify the "number of lines" occupied by the block-quote. Here's a small example using dummy text created by [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[25]{r}{.4\linewidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\centering
``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Proin ac tempus dui. Etiam non mattis neque. Maecenas tempor, 
massa a luctus sollicitudin, elit massa auctor velit, eu mattis 
lacus arcu nec est. Sed et lectus non tellus posuere consequat. 
Donec congue lacinia urna a iaculis. Cras id nisl sed sapien 
euismod rhoncus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Proin ac tempus dui. Etiam non mattis neque. Maecenas tempor, 
massa a luctus sollicitudin, elit massa auctor velit, eu mattis 
lacus arcu nec est. Sed et lectus non tellus posuere consequat. 
Donec congue lacinia urna a iaculis. Cras id nisl sed sapien 
euismod rhoncus.''
\end{minipage}}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
​
```

Read the [`wrapfig` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) for more information on the environment specification for `wrapfigure`.

Note that this will be problematic if the block-quote spans beyond the page boundary.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have some difficulties to make it look good with multicols. It kind of screws up the layout. But it gives me some headstart.

Comment: @Mixhael: You didn't mention the requirement/usage of `multicols` in your question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link back to *this* question to provide the background.