# Block quote with big quotations - white on black

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation, quoting

There is are some very nice answers to the question of how to put large quotation marks around a block of text at [Block quote with big quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks). Using the first answer (which uses tikz) but with white text on a black background gives me a large white rectangle over the text. How can you change it to work with slides (I am using beamer) that have white text on a black background?

Example that gives the problematic white box over the text.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
% Make commands for the quotes
\newcommand*{\openquote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]
 \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};\kern0pt}
\newcommand*{\closequote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=15pt,yshift=10pt]
 \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};}
% select a colour for the shading
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Azure}
% wrap everything in its own environment
\newenvironment{shadequote}%
{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
{\hfill\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}

%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE showing this so that we don't have to guess at what packages/themes you're using, please?  This is the sort of question where that could make all the difference.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "large white rectangle over the text" is actually a large *Azure* rectangle *under* the text.  You can see this by changing the text colour to something else (black, for example).  This colour is positioned by the `snugshade` environment which comes from the `framed` package.  It's colour is determined by the colour `shadecolor`.  To remove it altogether, remove the `\begin{snugshade}` and `\end{snugshade}` from the definition of the `shadequote` environment.  To just change the colour, replace the `Azure` by something more fitting, say `Maroon`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
% Make commands for the quotes
\newcommand*{\openquote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]
 \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};\kern0pt}
\newcommand*{\closequote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=15pt,yshift=10pt]
 \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};}
% select a colour for the shading
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Maroon}
% wrap everything in its own environment
\newenvironment{shadequote}%
{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
{\hfill\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}

%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Change colour of shaded rectangle]

Comment: Thanks very much! Maybe this should be a separate question but I get the left quotes too near to the text and right quotes too far exactly as in your example. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Editing the xshift settings fixes it it seems.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, I noticed that too.  I suspect there are several things one could tweak to get the look just right.

Comment: Note that with TeX Live 2014 the `fxl` family name doesn't work and `\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}` should be used.