# How to get big quotation marks again

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation, quoting

I am trying to use this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67257/block-quote-with-big-quotations-white-on-black) to get large quotation marks,

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
% Make commands for the quotes
\newcommand*{\openquote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]
 \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};\kern0pt}
\newcommand*{\closequote}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=15pt,yshift=10pt]
 \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};}
% select a colour for the shading
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Maroon}
% wrap everything in its own environment
\newenvironment{shadequote}%
{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
{\hfill\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}

%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this now gives me miserable and skinny quotation marks instead. I heard that the libertine package had changed recently but I can't see how to fix this.  I am using TeX Live 2013.

The error I get is

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fxl/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 130.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the font family name has changed. You can use

```
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
```

I suggest also to change `\kern0pt` into `\kern4pt` or something else that avoids the quote bumping in the first character.

Note that `\RequirePackage` is not needed: the option to `xcolor` can be passed in the `\documentclass` line.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
% Make commands for the quotes
\newcommand*{\openquote}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]
  \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};%
  \kern4pt
}
\newcommand*{\closequote}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,xshift=15pt,yshift=10pt]
  \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};%
}
% select a colour for the shading
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Maroon}
% wrap everything in its own environment
\newenvironment{shadequote}
  {\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
  {\hfill\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}

%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]