# Quotes problem in beamer

Tags: beamer, errors, compiling, quoting

I'm trying to make nice big quotes work in my presentation, but there is some error, a clashing of packages I assume, and I don't know how to resolve this :
So my mwe is here:

```
%&latex
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={breaklinks=true},mathserif,10pt]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=RoyalPurple]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@right
\def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
\def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
\def\endshadequote{%
  \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
\@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
\@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
\makeatother

%\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{logo.eps}}

\title{RANDOM TITLE}
\subtitle{Random subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\institute[Random institute at random place}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Intro}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intro}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[]
        \flushleft{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{elvish.eps}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{shadequote}
        A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
        foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
        \end{shadequote}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Basically I'd like to have image on the left and next to it (on the right) two quotes.
I followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks), but I guess I made sth wrong :\ I didn't want any shade underneath my quotes so I left out the `colorlet` part...

So any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Summary

- You must not leave the `\colorlet` part out as that is important in the definition of `\shadequote`, I think, based on the error I get:

```
Package xcolor error: Undefined error 'shadecolor'\end{frame}
```

- The `svgnames` was important for the color name `Azure` so you may use the option `xcolor={svgnames, dvipsnames}`. Or if you don't want to load `svgnames`, use more generic colors or combination of them in your `\colorlet{shadecolor}`. If you don't want shading in your quote, use `\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}` instead. In that case, `svgnames` may not be loaded.
- the `mathserif` option is already deprecated. Use `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` instead.
- There is a scoping problem in `\institute[Random institute at random place}`. I changed `[` to `}`.
- Compile with the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` sequence.

## Revised Code

```
%&latex
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}
,hyperref={breaklinks=true}
%,mathserif
,10pt]{beamer} 
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=RoyalPurple]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@right
\def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
\def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
\def\endshadequote{%
  \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
\@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
\@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
\makeatother

%\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{logo.eps}}

\title{RANDOM TITLE}
\subtitle{Random subtitle}
\author{John Doe}
\institute{Random institute at random place}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Intro}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intro}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item[]
        \flushleft{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{elvish.eps}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{shadequote}
        A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
        foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
        \end{shadequote}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! Is there any way I make the shading transparent? Because I have a logo in the lower right corner, and when using `\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}` it covers my logo :|

Also, how can I change the quotes symbols? The lmodern ones are quite ugly XD

Comment: AFAIK transparency does not work well with `postscript`. Andrew Stacey's answer in your linked post will yield easier to a transparent quote node. You can manually place the location of the quote higher perhaps.

Comment: I have 'solved' the problem by putting another quote right under it and thus blocking the logo all together XD But thanks :D

Comment: I cannot seem to get any other font to work :\ All fonts I use end up being ugly... Any info on that?

Comment: If it is about the quotation marks then it is because you are using `sans serif`. Try serif for the quotation marks and you will see the difference.

Comment: Oh, that `[onlymath]` code interfered with everything :D

Comment: Yes, you can remove that if you want. I put it there since you were using `mathserif` option to your original code. Doing so will only make your math texts to be serif, the rest sans.

Comment: Yeah, that was there by default. This looks better :D Thanks :)