# quotes at start of every chapter

Tags: chapters, quoting, epigraphs

I want to make quotes like the following image at the start of a chapter, but I can't seem to find how :(

This is what i been using for Now but i like this one. Can you help with that. thanks :) have a good day

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%*************************************************
% fancy quotes
\definecolor{quotemark}{gray}{0.7}
\makeatletter
\def\fquote{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@i}{\fquote@i[]}%]
}

\def\fquote@i[#1]{%
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@ii}{\fquote@ii[]}%]
}%

\def\fquote@ii[#1]{%
  \def\tempb{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@iii}{\fquote@iii[]}%]
}%

\def\fquote@iii[#1]{%
  \def\tempc{#1}%
  \vspace{1em}%
  \noindent%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
  }%
    \item[]%
      \begin{picture}(0,0)%
        \put(-15,-5){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{3}
          {\textcolor{quotemark}{``}}}}%
      \end{picture}%
      \begingroup\itshape}%
\def\endfquote{%
  \endgroup\par%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace{0.8\textwidth}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(0,0)%
      \put(15,15){\makebox(0,0){%
        \scalebox{3}{\color{quotemark}''}}}%
    \end{picture}}%
  \ifx\tempa\empty%
  \else%
    \ifx\tempc\empty%
      \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\
      \emph{\tempb}%
    \else%
      \hfill\rule{100pt}{0.5pt}\\\mbox{}\hfill\tempa,\
      \emph{\tempb},\ \tempc%
    \fi\fi\par%
  \vspace{0.5em}%
  \end{list}}
\makeatother

%%%*********************************************

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Graph theory}
  \begin{fquote}[Confucius]Our greatest glory is not in
    never falling, but in rising every time we fall.
  \end{fquote}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{fquote}[Lewis Carroll][Alice in Wonderland]
    [1899]Begin at the beginning,'' the King said,
    gravely, ``
  \end{fquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for being thick, but can you explain what exactly you are asking again? The code you posted *roughly* produces something similar to the picture. Do you want the output to look more like the picture? If so, please explain what exactly needs to be changed in more detail.

Comment: yeah i want the output similar to the picture :)

Comment: It would still help if you could list exactly what you want to have changed from the status quo, but maybe that is just me. The original code seems to come from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53452/35864. Possibly interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16964/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98984/35864

Comment: I want the format and the position of quotation mark and the vspace between the quote and chapter title

Comment: I saw this kind of block quotes but not actually what i wanted can you just tell me how can i modify just the format and position of quotation mark?? that will be enough for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon [pluton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/371/pluton)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53452/35864) to ["Inspirational" quote at start of chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53377/35864) we can come up with the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{quotemark}{gray}{0.7}
\makeatletter
\newlength\origparskip

\newcommand{\fquote}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@i}{\fquote@i[]}%]
}

\def\fquote@i[#1]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\fquote@ii{#1}}{\fquote@ii{#1}[]}%]
}%

\def\fquote@ii#1[#2]{%
  \def\pqm@tempa{#1}%
  \def\pqm@tempb{#2}%
  \noindent
  \list
    {}
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.3\textwidth}%
     \setlength{\rightmargin}{0.1\textwidth}%
     \setlength{\origparskip}{\parskip}}%
    \item[]%
      \begin{picture}(0,0)%
        \put(-15,-8){\makebox(0,0){\scalebox{4}{%
          \textcolor{quotemark}{\textquotedblright}}}}%
      \end{picture}%
      \begingroup
      \itshape
      \ignorespaces}%

\def\endfquote{%
  \endgroup
  \par
  \raggedleft
  \ifx\pqm@tempa\empty
  \else
    {\bfseries --- \pqm@tempa\par}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\origparskip}%
    \ifx\pqm@tempb\empty
    \else
      (\pqm@tempb)%
    \fi
  \fi
  \par
  \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Graph theory}
  \begin{fquote}[Wim Crouwel][Graphic designer and typographer]
    You can’t do better design with a computer, but you can speed up your work enormously.
  \end{fquote}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{fquote}[Wim Crouwel]
    You can’t do better design with a computer, but you can speed up your work enormously.
  \end{fquote}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The code has been changed to output only the opening quotation mark and `fquote` only accepts two optional arguments now: One for the name and one for the parenthetical insertion.

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: Should the quotes be opening?

Comment: @Sigur Let's say they are opening in the sense of the question `;-)`. If you shift them down a tiny bit they would work as German opening quotes as well (which are „Gänsefüßchen“ 99-bottom and 66-top).

Comment: Thta is exactly what i want thank youuuuu so much @moewe

Comment: how can i add space between the quote and the text ?@moewe

Comment: and thank you again I really appreciate your help:)

Comment: @AlexiaColaud Remove the `%` first in `%\vspace{0.5em}` and adjust the number to your liking.

Comment: I tried the code but i didn't get the same quotation mark may be because I have in my preambule : \usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}

Comment: If I delet the options that will impact the quotation mark in my text too ?

Comment: @AlexiaColaud Even with `\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}` I get the same quotation marks in the MWE. The result might be slightly different depending on your font, but the overall appearance should at least be similar. If you get something wildly different, please prepare a full MWE that reproduces the undesired behaviour and show it.

Comment: yeah i get a different quotation mark <<   << wwhen i delet the options I get the same result as shown in your code

Comment: @AlexiaColaud (1) Where do you get that quotation mark? (2) Please show me a complete example document that reproduces the behaviour. I could *not* reproduce it only by adding `\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}` to the code above, even after changing to `french` as the main language I still get a big "„" in front of the quotation. Of course inside the epigraph things might be different. But I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly, so *I need to see the code*.

Comment: its good now I did recompile the code twice with the \usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes} and now i get the same quotation mark thank youuuuuu @moewe :) you are the best

Comment: @AlexiaColaud Very good. Glad I could help.

Comment: @moewe I am getting the following error from your code when I try to implement it in an overleaf document Extra \else.

"\@include ...ediate \closeout \@partaux \fi \else 
                                                  \deadcycles \z@ \@nameuse ...
l.57 \include{Main/Chap1/Intro}
                               
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if".  I am not sure which  IF condition it refers to. It still produces the quote design you posted but I wasn't able to remove the error. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @SaraKrauss The code as posted compiles fine for me both on my local machine as well as on Overleaf. If you get errors that's probably because some other code in your preamble interferes with the code here. I think I will only be able to say more if you can show me a short example document that reproduces the error.

Comment: @SaraKrauss There was a missing `\fi`. I edited the answer and added it.

Comment: @moewe thank you very much. It works! now I can start my thesis in peace

Comment: @moewe btw Is it possible to move the quote before the chapter? I mean at the top right of the page above the chapter text? I could not figure out where to edit for that?

Comment: @SaraKrauss On first glance I'd think that would be (much?) harder, because the `\chapter` command starts a new page. So you can't just use this environment before `\chapter`. If you really want an answer, I suggest you ask a new question (the document class is going to be important, so make sure your MWE for the question uses the actual document class and heading settings of your document.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understood exactly what you want, but this is what I propose, based on `epigraph`. I replaced the obsolete `times`  package with `newtxtext, newtxmath` based on the Times clone `TeX Gyre Termes`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%*************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.6\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
%%%*********************************************
\newcommand{\myopeningquote}{\smash{\raisebox{-1.25\height}{\llap{\scalebox{3}
          {\textcolor{Silver}{``}}\,}}}}
\newcommand{\myclosingquote}{\raisebox{-0.66\height}{\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{Silver}{”}}}}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Graph theory}

\epigraph{\itshape\myopeningquote Our greatest glory is not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.\myclosingquote}
{Confucius}%

  \lipsum[2]

\epigraph{\itshape\myopeningquote Begin at the beginning,'' the King said,
    gravely,\myclosingquote}
{Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland} (1865)}%

  \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]