# csquotes, makeblockquote and big quotation marks

Tags: csquotes

I am trying to enable big quotation marks, as in a previously answered post her: [Block quote with big quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16964/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks)

However, I would like to use it with csquotes, and the makeblockquote-command. Anyone who knows how to achieve this effect?

```
\documentclass[11pt, norsk]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\MakeBlockQuote{<}{|}{>}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] <\lipsum[2]>

Some random text right here just to show <Some quoted text not in block>
\end{document}
```