# Putting an enumerate list into quotation marks

Tags: enumerate, punctuation

I have a question: How can one put quotation marks around a list, i.e. like this:

```
"1. item one

...

n. item n"
```

I need to cite a list in my document.

(I will need to use German quotation marks, but I believe having this solved for classic ones, the rest should be easy)

Comment: Welcome to the site! you could, for example, wrap a `tcolorbox` around it; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277777/block-quote-with-big-quotation-marks-in-margin/277819#277819, for example :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer :). I might try that but it does not feel really science-y (and I believe it should, since I am writing a bachelor thesis). Initially, I was aiming for a look similar to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226839/how-to-quote-a-list
but without the quotations at the beginning of each item line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}      
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\itemquote{\textooquote}
\robustify\itemquote

\begin{enumerate}[label=\itemquote\arabic*]
\item blub
\let\itemquote\relax %deactivate quote

\item blub\textcoquote
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, does exactly what I had in mind. Also, out of interest, is there any difference between \textcoquote and \grqq?