# How to make the opening and closing quotation-marks look bigger in quotes?

Tags: color, quotation, mylatexformat

I am currently writing a paper that includes quotes. But I am not satisfied with the obtained result; I want to make the quotes look more attractive. To do so, the idea is to make them appear bigger than the text and then be colorful. I've tried the `\big` and `\Big` followed by `\textcolor{}{}` commands, but they didn't work.
For the moment, the quotes look like this...
[image]

And the corresponding code is the following...

```
``\textsf{...there was little I could teach \textit{Fermi}, and often I asked him to teach me something instead.}''\\ \par
\hspace{5.2cm}\boldsymbol{-} \textit{Luigi Puccianti}\\
```

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Comment: You might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16964/35864 and linked discussions.

Comment: @moewe That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the `epigraph` package for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{8cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{epigraphs}
\qitem{\large ...there was little I could teach \textit{Fermi}, and often I asked him to teach me something instead.}
{--- \textit{Luigi Puccianti}}
\end{epigraphs}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

By default, the text is flushed to the right, but you can use `\epigraphflush` to move it elsewhere (see the first few pages of the doc).

Inside the `\qitem` macro you can use all normal text commands to enhance the appearence of the text.

Comment: thank you so much for responding. Indeed, I'm not trying to make the text bigger, instead, I want to modify the size of the quotation marks (``....''). The size of the text seems ok to me and its font as well. I found the fruitful solution in the link given by @moewe above. Thanks a lot again for the help.